# Get index of item in array that is a column in a Spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am able to filter a Spark dataframe (in PySpark) based on if a particular value exists within an array field by doing the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import array_contains
spark_df.filter(array_contains(spark_df.array_column_name, "value that I want")).show()
```

Is there a way to get the index of where in the array the item was found?  It seems like that should exist, but I am not finding it.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using spark 2.3 version, so I tried this using udf.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(["c", "b", "a","e","f"],)], ['arraydata'])
+---------------+
|      arraydata|
+---------------+
|[c, b, a, e, f]|
+---------------+

user_func = udf (lambda x,y: [i for i, e in enumerate(x) if e==y ])
```

## checking index position for item 'b':

```
newdf = df.withColumn('item_position',user_func(df.arraydata,lit('b')))

>>> newdf.show();
+---------------+-------------+
|      arraydata|item_position|
+---------------+-------------+
|[c, b, a, e, f]|          [1]|
+---------------+-------------+
```

## checking index position for item 'e':

```
newdf = df.withColumn('item_position',user_func(df.arraydata,lit('e')))

>>> newdf.show();
+---------------+-------------+
|      arraydata|item_position|
+---------------+-------------+
|[c, b, a, e, f]|          [3]|
+---------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 13):

In spark 2.4+, there's the [`array_position`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_position) function:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([(["c", "b", "a"],), ([],)], ['data'])
df.show()
#+---------+
#|     data|
#+---------+
#|[c, b, a]|
#|       []|
#+---------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import array_position
df.select(df.data, array_position(df.data, "a").alias('a_pos')).show()
#+---------+-----+
#|     data|a_pos|
#+---------+-----+
#|[c, b, a]|    3|
#|       []|    0|
#+---------+-----+
```

Notes from the docs:

1. Locates the position of **only the first occurrence of the given value** in the given array;
2. The position is not zero based, but 1 based index. Returns 0 if the given value could not be found in the array.

Comment: So this feature exists only with version 2.4?

Comment: @vikrantrana Yes. It's new in version 2.4

Comment: Does this function exists for scala with spark?